# How to change value inside a JSON string

Tags: json

I have a <s>JSON</s> <s>string</s> array of objects like this.

```
[{"id":"4","rank":"adm","title":"title 1"},
{"id":"2","rank":"mod","title":"title 2"},
{"id":"5","rank":"das","title":"title 3"},
{"id":"1","rank":"usr","title":"title 4"},
{"id":"3","rank":"ref","title":"title 5"}]
```

I want to change the title value of it, once the id is matching. So if my variable myID is 5, I want to change the title "title 5" to new title, and so on. And then I get the new JSON array to `$("#rangArray").val(jsonStr);`

Something like

```
$.each(jsonStr, function(k,v) {
    if (v==myID) {
        this.title='new title'; $("#myTextArea").val(jsonStr);
    }
});
```

Here is the full code.

```
$('img.delete').click(function() {
var deltid = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
var newID = deltid[1];
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(myArray);
$.each(jsonStr, function(k,v) {
if (v==newID) {
// how to change the title
jsonStr[k].title = 'new title';
alert(jsonStr);
$("#rangArray").val(jsonStr);
}
});
});
```

The above is not working. Any help please?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your array literal: you have two commas `,,` in row two.

Comment: Can OP change the title to avoid misleading other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(jsonStr, function(i,v) {
    if ( v.id == myID ) {
        v.title = 'new title';
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/CVvW4/1/

---

Full snipped (with my code implemented):

```
$('img.delete').click(function() {
    var newID = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];

    $.each(myArray, function(i,v) {
        if ( v.id == newID ) {
            v.title = 'new title';
            $('#rangArray').val(jsonStr);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sime, but here > `if ( jsonStr[k].id == v ) {` I need to compare the value of v with a previously defined variable. What do you think.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Many many thanks. I really appreciate for your help (and sorry for the delayed reply, I had to go out for some work suddenly). It's good, but I have this issue of "undefined". In the line `if (v.id == newID) {` I am getting the value of `v.id` as undefined, and hence the whole if condition is not getting executed. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Jeremy I've updated my code. Try now. (I've passed the myArray variable into the $.each method directly.)

Comment: @Šime Vidas Cool, and this solves the problem wonderfully. Many many thanks once again, Sime. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `jsonStr[k].title = 'new title';`

Comment: Thanks for the new one, but it's still not working. or probably, it's working but I'm not able to see it, in #myTextArea or even using an alert just after `jsonStr[k].title = 'new title'; alert(jsonStr);`. I have even tried `jsonStr[2].title = 'new title';` (replacing k with 2, just to check if that changes the 3rd element of the array), it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `jsonStr[v].title = "new title";`

Your `jsonStr` is an array of objects.